# Least root closer to the local max than greatest root for cubic polynomial with three real roots?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Suppose we have a cubic polynomial $f(x)$ with three unique real roots whose leading coefficient is positive. If $f$ has roots $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, a local max at $y_1$, and a local min at $y_2$, then the shape of $f$ implies $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < x_3$. I am wondering if the smallest root is always closer to the local max than the largest root. In other words, is it true that $$y_1 - x_1 < x_3 - y_1?$$ Thank you!

Comment: It seems can be proved using $f(x)$ has a point of symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_2=0$. Then $x_1<0<x_3$.

Solving $f'(x)=0$ we find $2y_1=\frac23(x_1+x_3-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_3^2-x_1x_3})$

Because $x_1^2+x_3^2-x_1x_3-\frac14(x_1+x_3)^2=\frac34(x_1-x_3)^2>0$

We have $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_3^2-x_1x_3}>-\frac12(x_1+x_3)\Leftrightarrow2y_1<x_1+x_3$

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but $$\frac{2}{3}(x_1 + x_3) < x_1 + x_3$$ might not be true if $x_1 + x_3 < 0$.

Comment: @JLinsta Yes. I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you so much!